# Is it safe to access view instances using Ember.View.views on production environment also or it is there only for debugging purpose?

Tags: ember.js

I have a requirement to update view templates dynamically and my views instances are not global, so I am thinking to use `Ember.View.views` for accessing view instances and to update template. So, I need some suggestions whether to use this approach or not, because it will be used in live site also.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is only for debugging purpose. You should not need to access to the view using this way

Comment: I've never needed to use the `.views` to do anything. Unless you can prove me wrong, if you're needing this approach, then you're using EmberJS wrong. Could you please provide us with a JSFiddle to exemplify what you're trying to achieve, Venkata? Template: http://jsfiddle.net/Ync94/

Comment: @Wildhoney, we have a feature to **update the view template and re-render dynamically**, for this I need the view's instance to invoke re-render method, so is there any way get all the view instances present in an application? 

JS Fiddle is available here - [http://jsfiddle.net/VenkataSuresh/XCA4N/](http://jsfiddle.net/VenkataSuresh/XCA4N/)

Comment: checkout the fiddle in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Ember.View.views` hash and do `rerender`, you can recreate the fiddle that you mentioned in your Question comments using `Ember.ContainerView` in a better way, I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Unspecified/QEfCG/) for you, Have a look